# java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted

Tags: jenkins, jnlp

I/we(the company) have a weird issue with Jenkins and the connection between Master and Slave.
After a while the connection is rejected/timed out for some reason.

We tried to start it as a Windows Service but that didn't go well(also error message). We try it again, maybe we didn't start it properly.

Below is the error Message(3) and the error from the Server(1) and slave(2)

How can we/I resolve this?
I read that this is still a bug in Jenkins but is there really no workaround?

---

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R570J.png),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1mlO.png),[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR79M.png)

Comment: Okay for anyone who has the same problem...We tried to install it as a Windows Service and now it works and the slave is stable for the last few hours.